Is Lorentz force velocity dependent or length dependent?
I am trying to research Lorentz force for a project I am doing and something that has troubled me is whether or not Lorentz forces depend on the velocity of a charged particle or whether they depend on the length of a charged object. I found two calculators both from the same website where one webpage states that it is dependent on velocity here while the other states that it needs length here. So if we have a charged object moving at a speed of 1 m/s and we expose it to a magnetic field what will matter more its length or its velocity? Also keep in mind that I am using the information I got off of the pages so I might not know certain important things so try to keep this in terms a high schooler can understand.
For example if we put 1000 amperes in an object and put a magnetic field through it will the force be velocity dependent or length dependent.

Lorentz force $\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$ depends only on velocity of the receiving electron (not velocity of the source electron). All treatments having terms like $I, n, l$ etc. are higher level "operator algebra" built on the basic per electron $\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B$, and usually have other names like "Faraday's law", "Ampere's law", attached to the equation.

It's a good example of confusing historical naming conventions. OTOH, it is kind of hard to mistake a feely moving charge for a current through a wire. In one case there is a wire and in the other case there isn't.

All the best. In principle I believe one can do all of high school eletromagnetism from $\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$. In your shoes, I would focus primarily on this equation for the project, as it simplifies the chapter-after-chapter of EM formula headaches i got from high school physics :)

Btw, you would need to know also the other half of the picture, that every electron gives off $E$ and $B$ of its own, so suppose there is an electron here moving with such and such velocity, this electron contributes an $E$ and $B$ to every point in space, whose information is then used by other electrons for deciding where to move next in the presence of this electron.
